# Kubeclt exec issues with variable via php script

Tags: php, kubernetes, kubectl

New to kubernetes and php, so I'm having some issues.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
$postgres = 'kubectl get pods -n migrationnamespace | grep postgres | cut -d " " -f1 2>&1';
$postgres_pod = shell_exec($postgres);
echo $postgres_pod;

$list2 = 'kubectl exec -it -n migrationnamespace ' . $postgres_pod . ' -- psql -U postgres -c \'SELECT * FROM mywhales\'; 2>&1';
echo "<pre>";
echo shell_exec($list2);
echo "<pre>";
?>
```

results in error

```
postgres-7957478b7d-tmw6m
error: you must specify at least one command for the container
sh: line 1: --: command not found
```

When switching `'.$postgres_pod.'` for `postgres-7957478b7d-tmw6m` as below - it executes fully

```
$list2 = 'kubectl exec -it -n migrationnamespace postgres-7957478b7d-tmw6m -- psql -U postgres -c \'SELECT * FROM mywhales\';';

postgres-7957478b7d-tmw6m
  whale  
---------
 16:117
 ......
 561:539
(17 rows)
```

Thanks - Mike

Comment: Worth checking what `$postgres_pod` contains and see if there is any whitespace around it, or just try `trim($postgres_pod)`

Comment: thanks @NigelRen `$postgres_trim = trim($postgres_pod);` and `'.$postgres_trim.'` has got it sorted

Comment: Using a [Kubernetes client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) will almost always be more robust than shelling out to `kubectl`; the documentation link includes several for PHP and one of these might work for you.

Comment: Good point @DavidMaze - thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can sometimes be extra whitespace before or after strings, especially return characters which don't always show up when `echo`ing the result.

Using `trim($postgres_pod)` will ensure they are removed.